# Insert results of 2 collections into a new model

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a wpf c# app.
I have to list collections.
I want to join these 2 lists and return the results that match a criteria.
I want the result to be loaded into a new list/model.

This is my code so far:

```
var Results = from j in res
             join c in Customer.GetBaseData() on j.CustomerRef equals c.CustomerRef
             where j.JobStatusRef == jobStatusRef                  
             select new {
                 c.CustomerRef,
                 c.CustomerId,
                 c.Add1,
                 c.Town,
                 c.FName,
                 c.SName,
                 j.DateReq,
                 j.JobId,
                 j.JobRef,
                 j.JobStatus
             };
```

This is my destination model:

```
public class CustomerJobs
{
    public int JobId { get; set; }     
    public string CustomerRef { get; set; }
    public string DateReq { get; set; }     
    public string JobRef { get; set; }      
    public string JobStatus { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string SName { get; set; }
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string Add1 { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
}
```

I do not know how to do this final step?

Comment: how to insert into this model

Comment: Into what exactly? "a new list/model" What is that?

Comment: Instead of `Select new { ...}`  do  `Select new CustomerJobs {...}` ?

Comment: Why not expand that and create an answer of it? @Gilgamesh

Comment: down voter and closer sorry for askign such a dumb question. I did not know how to convert from anonymous type to the model

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of creating an anonymous type with `new { ... }`, directly use your model in the select:

```
var Results = from j in res
         join c in Customer.GetBaseData() on j.CustomerRef equals c.CustomerRef
         where j.JobStatusRef == jobStatusRef
         // Note the "new CustomerJobs" part.                  
         select new CustomerJobs {
             c.CustomerRef,
             c.CustomerId,
             c.Add1,
             c.Town,
             c.FName,
             c.SName,
             j.DateReq,
             j.JobId,
             j.JobRef,
             j.JobStatus
         };
```

Answer (score 3):

When you select in linq you can specify the type of the object like:

```
var Results = from j in res
             join c in Customer.GetBaseData() on j.CustomerRef equals c.CustomerRef
             where j.JobStatusRef == jobStatusRef                  
             select new CustomerJobs {
                CustomerRef = c.CustomerRef,
                CustomerId = c.CustomerId,
                Add1 = c.Add1,
                Town = c.Town,
                FName = c.FName,
                SName = c.SName,
                DateReq = j.DateReq,
                JobId = j.JobId,
                JobRef = j.JobRef,
                JobStatus = j.JobStatus
             };
```

Comment: thanks zippy it was want I wanted but the other answer was the same but just before you